# Any way to move an o365 Teams Channel to another Team?

Tags: move, microsoft-teams

I created 5 channels under my manager's o365 Team and now there was a reorg and need to move them (or conversations at least) to another Team.

Any way to do this with OOTB o365 Teams?  or anybody know if possible with the ShareGate migration tool?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is not possible.  You can register your vote to Teams User Voice.

Apparently the status was only updated recently to 'Needs your Feedback'.  Please go to user voice and add your feedback. https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/16939708-move-channels-into-other-teams

Answer (score 0):

At this point it is **still not possible** to move channels between teams.

**BUT**: Microsoft is working on this feature as it was pushed on [uservoice for teams](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/16939708-move-channels-into-other-teams). On the other hand this feature is not mentioned on the [Microsoft Teams roadmap](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=In%20Development%2CMicrosoft%20Teams#owRoadmapMainContent) yet. So I assume launch is not planned within short term but feature will be available in the future.

Answer (score 0):

We've just released a 3rd-party solution that allows is.
You can move, export and archive Microsoft Teams channels with our solution, [SphereShield for Microsoft Teams](https://agatsoftware.com/microsoft-teams-channel-management/), and you can sign up for a free trial.

Answer (score 0):

X Unfortunately this feature is missing in Microsoft Teams.

✓ However, there's a third party solution called SphereShield Channel Management  that does it.

https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/web-apps/agatsoftwaredevelopmentltd1592480580416.channel-management

Here's the official Website: https://agatsoftware.com/microsoft-teams-channel-management/

All the best!